# CURL não esta funcionando localmente

Tags: php, laravel-5

Pessoal tenho 2 aplicações em Laravel 5.5 rodando localmente. Uma é a API e a outra é um frontend. A API eu configurei ela como um vhost no WAMP Server como o nome api2018.local e configurei o CORS no Laravel para esta rota de APIs. Até ai tudo bem. Na aplicação frontend eu rodo via artisan serve e consigo ter acesso a API usando o CURL do PHP sem problemas. Mas ai eu configurei um vhost chamado frontend2018.local no Wamp server. Ai só consigo obter erro 500 no CURL. Alguém sabe por que isto? Obrigado

Comment: Provavelmente você está usando dois serviços na mesma porta.

Comment: Valeu @ValdeirPsr, era isto mesmo. Se você quiser posta como resposta para eu te marcar. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece quando utilizamos dois serviços na mesma porta, normalmente a porta `80`. Isso gera um conflito e o código acaba não sendo processo por nenhum deles. Para corrigir precisamos alterar a porta deles, neste caso, dê preferencia para alterar a porta do *WampServer*, já que ele inicia de forma automática, sem a necessidade de configura-lo todas as vezes.

---

#### Alterando a porta no WampServer

Para alterar a porta desse serviço, precisamos alterar um arquivo. Para isso podemos acessar a pasta `config` do *Apache*. Essa — normalmente — fica em `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache<versão>\conf`. Ao encontra-la, basta abrir o arquivo `httpd.conf` e localizar o código abaixo:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

Feito isso, basta alterar os valores `:80` para um outro valor entre `0` e `65537`, por exemplo:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```

Feito isso, basta reiniciar o servidor.

> Verificar se não há outros serviços rodando na porta.

**Dica:** Uma outra forma é clica no ícone do *WampServer* próximo ao relógio do *Windows* **>** *Apache* **>** *httpd.conf*

---

#### Utilizando outras portas no *artisan*

No *artisan* é mais simples, basta executar o comando abaixo.

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```